# Calculating Function from Variable 1 after Eliminating Level(s) from Variable 2 Using R

Tags: r, mean, subset

This question is asking which command to use given the following situation:

**Objective**: Calculate mean of iris$Sepal.Length.

**Constraint**: Do not include the iris$Species 'setosa'.

**My Work**:

```
data(iris)
levels(iris$Species)
```

output: setosa, versicolor, and virginica

```
mean(iris$Sepal.Length, which(iris$Species != 'setosa'))
```

output: error message 'incompatible dimensions'

**---**

This demo is a stand-in for my own dataset, where I want to calculate a function for a variable (such as Sepal.Length) that excludes levels from a second variable (such as Species). I believe my personal dataset and this stand-in demo are comparable.

Perhaps which() is not the appropriate command. What is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, try this

```
mean(iris$Sepal.Length[which(iris$Species != 'setosa')])
```

or

```
mean(iris$Sepal.Length[iris$Species != 'setosa'])
```

or

```
mean(iris[iris$Species!= "setosa", "Sepal.Length"])
```

Comment: great! thank you! how do I go about adding a second species to the != list?

Comment: use the `not in` logic, i.e. `mean(iris$Sepal.Length[ !(iris$Species %in% c('setosa', 'virginica')])`. The logic is: take `iris$Sepal.Length` where NOT `iris$Species` in `c('setosa', 'virginica')`